# How do I show multiple pathways in a userflow?

Tags: flow, deliverables

I'm trying to show different user paths in a deliverable. I want to create a user flow but I'm finding this difficult as the user can click on many different buttons on each page to get to the final destination.

For example: from the landing page, a user can click on support button, login button, or dashboard button (which are all on the same page) to get to the end of the flow.

Does anyone know a way around this? Maybe by specifying which button they're clicking within the page?

Comment: hi Taylor, welcome to UX.SE. Could you provide some visuals/ examples of the user flow? Or describe what area/ problem you are working on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate flowcharts with variants to create a summary visualization](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/142512/aggregate-flowcharts-with-variants-to-create-a-summary-visualization)

Answer (score 1):

**Use labels on or near your connector lines to show which action the user is choosing.** This example from [How to Improve App Settings](https://www.toptal.com/designers/ux/settings-ux) shows diverging paths based on system responses, and those labels could also be used to show user responses through clicks without making thumbnails that are too detailed.

[image: Wire flow with labels]

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine how this information would be documented or implemented in a prototyping tool like Adobe XD or MarvelApp, what you would be doing is associating a hotspot or an action with a page by drawing an arrow between the two. That's just one way of doing this but obviously it depends on how many buttons you have and how many pages it is going to.

With visualisation there is always a trade-off between the completeness of information at one glance (i.e. how much you need to drill in to get all the details) versus how easy it is to understand the information. If you can provide an example of how complex or how much information you have to capture, it will be easier to work out the best way to show it within the space you have to work with.